# Method invoking twice when using TestNG in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, inheritance, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have tried to implement inheritance in Selenium Web Driver. In Countrychoser class, I have called Basic() method from Baseurl Class.When I tried to execute in TestNG,Browser invoked twice. But in TestNG.xml, I have mentioned Countrychoser class only.

**Baseurl.java**

```
package MyTestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Baseurl {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public static void basic()
    {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get("http://www.sears.com/shc/s/CountryChooserView?storeId=10153&catalogId=12605");
    }
    public static void Closebrowser()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Countrychoser.java**

```
package MyTestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Countrychoser extends Baseurl 
{
@Test
    public static void Choser()
    {
    try
    {

    Baseurl.basic();
    //driver.findElement(By.className("box_countryChooser")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("intselect")).sendKeys("India");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='countryChooser']/a/img")).click();
    //window.onbeforeunload = null;
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Country choser layer test case-Success");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        }


    catch(Exception e) 
    {
           Screenshot.pageScreenshot();
           System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Country choser layer test case Failed");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
          }

    finally {

           Screenshot.pageScreenshot();  
           Baseurl.Closebrowser();
          }
    }
}
```

**TestNG.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >

  <test name="First" >
    <classes>
       <class name="MyTestNG.Countrychoser" />
    </classes>
  </test> 
  </suite>
```

Comment: what your question or problem?

Comment: Please try and adhere to Java naming conventions when doing Java: package names should be lowercase only, method names should be camelCase.

Comment: In Countrychoser class,I have extended Baseurl.When I mention Countrychoser class in TestNG xml.Browser details should be inherited from Baseurl class and it should invoke only once.But now browser is loading twice.Thats the problem.

Comment: Anybody can able to sort out,why browser is loading twice?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Countrychoser` class extends `Baseurl` , so it's now a `Baseurl` too and rightfully has `basic()` method which is annotated as a test method.

Thus, `basic()` makes into the execution list. 
So does `Choser()` method (as expected) that invokes `basic()` method again, hence `basic()` runs twice in total.

To avoid it you either don't inherit `Baseurl` or get rid of `@Test` annotation for `basic()`. 
You could probably have a parent class that provides `driver` (and has no test methods) and inherit it in `Base` and `Countrychoser` (these two being siblings).